# Main chat feeds double-post Skyrim/MW3 questions

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, chat

[Someone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=2350450#2350450), probably in retribution for me [complaining about something else](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/steam-events-need-to-be-more-descriptive), decided to cause me more irritation with [the main chatroom ("The Bridge") feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge?tab=feeds).

> #### Message feeds
>
> Recent Questions - Gaming - Stack Exchange posted by Lazers
>   Recent Questions - Gaming Meta - Stack Exchange posted by Lazers
>
> #### Ticker feeds
>
> newest questions tagged modern-warfare-3 - Gaming - Stack Exchange posted by Stack Exchange
>   newest questions tagged skyrim - Gaming - Stack Exchange posted by Stack Exchange

The Message feeds (ones that are like chat messages) are set to post all new questions on Gaming.SE, but the Ticker feeds (those at the top in a little box) include a sub-set of those; new MW3 or Skyrim questions.  Because one is a sub-set of the other, all the MW3/Skyrim questions are effectively duplicated.

Please fix.

Comment: That change was made earlier than the event you're mentioning, they're not connected.

Comment: Yes. Conspiracy theory. +1,000 @Fabian I've made time travel just to annoy Nick. Again. Because of aliens.

Comment: Why must you always blame the aliens? TAKE RESPONSIBILITY FOR YOUR ACTIONS. It's not the Martians fault.

Comment: [status-bydesign]  - Feeds are run independently of each other, so if they overlap in their topics, we will get duplicate posts. Also, now that the event is over (and the MW3/Skyrim feeds have been removed) this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. We need to take a closer look on MW3 and Skyrim questions during the event.
2. We can't have a main feed that doesn't show those two tags and another feed that only shows those two tags.
3. The only solution is having both, even if it causes repetition.

Please suggest fix.

---

If the popup feed is causing you excessive distress, for now I suggest clicking on "Ignore this user" [on this page to disable the Skyrim pop-up feed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-86/feeds-277) and/or [on this page to disable the MW3 pop-up feed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=modern-warfare-3&sort=newest).

Comment: No the truth is I really hate Nick's guts. He's bad and he should feel bad.

Comment: Excellent answer A++++++ would vote again